# Playing and Recording with a constant latency on browser with javascript usermedia and web audio api

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, audio-recording, web-audio-api, getusermedia

My application play a music using web audio api with MIDI.js.

Application record a user from microphone or webcam playing an instrument like guitar. I am using getUserMedia with a worker for this taken from https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs.

My problem is a latency problem.
The sound I played is approximately recorded 250ms after.

What I want is not necessarly to reduce this time but to know this time with more or less 15ms so I can synchronize both.

Is there anyway to do it ?
Can I assume the latency will stay constant ?

I noticed the AudioContext parameter call currentTime: http://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/#AudioContext-section
Can I use it to know the latency between my noteOn and the realTime noteOn on hardware ?
If yes then how and how can i get the latency between guitar playing and guitar recorded.

I need something like AudioIODevice::getOutputLatencyInSamples from JUCE    http://www.juce.com/api/classAudioIODevice.html#a693804fbf5a7cceb31ece10a9f03bd11

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Right now, there's no way to do this; the currentTime exposed is audio hardware time, and there's no direct conversion.  We have an open issue to add it to the spec.

Comment: So the problem would be to convert currentTime (audio card timer) to Javascript timer (base on computer clock ?)
250ms seems really huge, there is probably a way to reduce this time and approximate the delay.

Comment: It's system-dependent.  Latency is low on OSX, relatively low on Windows, high on Linux and other platforms.  You can approximate the jitter (currentTime is updated during block processing on the audio thread, so although it's monotonic, it's not consistently increasing - e.g. you could call window.performance.now(), call currentTime, call window.performance.now() and then call currentTime, and currentTime may not have changed), but you can't really know the latency today.

Comment: @cwilso I’m sure that the delay may be measured. Some popular web services (i.e. soundtrap.com) calculate it somehow, because they compensate latency while recording.

Comment: @crackbrain - they guess, typically by measuring the output-to-input latency (make a sound and listen for it) and cutting it in half.  If it's not symmetric, they'll be wrong.

Comment: @cwilso I thought so too, but then I checked carefully - they don't make any special sounds to measure latency. But they calculate the latency accurate within 15ms. It’s really intricate riddle!

Comment: @crackbrain - Soundtrap, in particular, just uses stored figures for average IO latency per platform (data they collect using Stephen Band's https://sound.io/latency - which essentially does what I suggested above), so if you have a higher-latency-than-average device, it will be off.  For built-in MacBook audio, for example, that's probably dead-on.  :)

Comment: @cwilso - Please, tell me where I can see this stored figures data? Is it open and free info?

Comment: I don't think so.  You'd have to ask Soundtrap.